# powershell executionPolicy message

Tags: powershell

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 'E:\Script-Popup\Trigger-Start-Popup.ps1'
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 'E:\Script-Popup\Popup-Message - Start.ps1'
powerShell -sta -file 'E:\Script-Popup\Popup-Message - Start.ps1' -Confrim:$true
```

[image]

The script always stops for me here and I want it to run automatically, I tried -Force I tried -Confrim:$true

What else can be done to have it automatically confirm it?

I don't mind putting echo Y and enter, a really stupid solution but I've already tried most of them..

Comment: You don't set the execution policy _per-file_. Perhaps you're looking for `Unblock-File 'E:\Script-Popup\Trigger-Start-Popup.ps1'`?

Comment: Set execution policy system-wide, e. g. `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`. This needs to be run as administrator once and then you no longer have to confirm everytime you run a script.

Comment: tried both of them same issue, we can do Y and enter? by powershell

Answer (score 0):

You can't put `Set-ExecutionPolicy` into a script (obviously) but you can use -Force on it. That will skip the confirmation prompt.

Do note that depending on the Scope you set for `Set-ExecutionPolicy` the policy you set might not have an effect on new powershell instances such as the one started in the third line.

Use Get-ExecutionPolicy -List to see which scope is set to what policy.

As an aside, you don't usually need to set -Confirm to $True as that is its default value (most of the time). Setting -Confirm to $true obviously won't skip any confirmation boxes; to do that you'd need to set it to $False instead.

Comment: ok and that info help me how?I already know that.
 I want to skip on that step

Comment: You put together a group policy or a registry entry to do that. You certainly don't use PS; Executionpolicies are already pretty much pointless as it is and if you could unset them programmatically -- on top of being able to just pass -Exec to any PS process then it'd be even worse than useless.